# Angular6 http post method does not pass data to web api

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

i am not receiving data on asp.net mvc core api from angular 6 app.
Image is here
[MVC core api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZgBH.png)

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };  

  createUser(user: User): Observable<any> {;
    let body = JSON.stringify(user);
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:51001/api/User/' + "PostUser", body, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Comment: **SHOW US THE CODE!** Post the relevant bits and pieces of Angular and Web API Code here - as text, properly formatted.

Comment: Just so you know, there's no need to add the `Content-Type` header, as Angular will add this in for you

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `JSON.stringify`, as the Angular `Http` / `HttpClient` class will do this for you. If you do it yourself, Angular will then call `stringify` on the string, which is causing the problem you're seeing.

```
  createUser(user: User): Observable<any> {;
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:51001/api/User/' + "PostUser", user, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```